# Using variables to define Array Size (Codeblocks)

Tags: c

I used this code in "codeblocks" and it worked like a charm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j, n, m;

   printf("Input n & m: "); 
   scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

   int a[n][m];

   //Reading Array Values
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
   }
   //Displaying Array Values
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
   }
}
```

But I saw some topics where people say that this is a kind of option which comes from gcc compiler actually. So I was wondering, should I use this in future or this is a wrong way?
I thought not having headache with vector function and i decided to do this way and it worked very well. I guess this will work only on the version of gcc compiler I use. But anyway, is there still a problem with that or I can use it smoothly?

Comment: VLA(variable length array) can be used with the C compiler since C99. However, since it is optional in C11, please check whether it can be used by your compiler to use.

Comment: Note that VLAs have never been implemented in MSVC. Now they have become optional in C11 that was .. ugh.

Comment: So basically I can use this type of compiler and create whatever application I want? There won't be problems in compiled code like slow execution time or some bugs?                                                                                                   I mean, using vector function instead of the method i posted should be trivial in this case?

Comment: "vector function"? Are you talking about C++ `std::vector`, or something else?

Comment: It is possible to run into trouble with VLAs because they may be subject to smaller implementation limits than, say, dynamically-allocated arrays.  There's no particular reason to fear slow execution, but you might indeed find that your program fails when implemented with VLAs but works when implemented with analogous static or dynamically-allocated arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no GCC compiler specifc behavior in your code.
I executed the same on gcc compiler. You can check the result here:

[jdoodle.com/a/biz](http://jdoodle.com/a/biz)

https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/c/gcc-5.3.0/biz

```html
<div data-pym-src="https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/c/gcc-5.3.0/biz"></div>
<script src="https://www.jdoodle.com/assets/jdoodle-pym.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```